# Make JButton Look Like It Has Input Focus

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Is there any way to make a JButton look like it has the input focus when it doesn't?

I am creating a search window that has a text area for the input and a 'Find Next' button to start the search.  I want the 'Find Next' button to appear to have the focus even though keyboard input is going to the text area.  The idea is notify the user that pressing `<Enter>` will start the search, similar to applications like Microsoft Word.

I know that I can paint the button myself, but I'm looking for an easier way.

Comment: Is the text component a JTextArea? Or is it a JTextField? If the latter, you can simply give it the same ActionListener or Action that you give your JButton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the same as input focus; it's just that the button should be the default button of the dialog.

Get the [`JRootPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html) using [`getRootPane()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getRootPane()) on your dialog/frame/window and use [`setDefaultButton`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton(javax.swing.JButton)) on that instead.

L&Fs might draw the default button even differently than one having input focus, so a user might be quite confused if there are two apparent controls having focus.